# How to define mutually recursive types

Tags: recursion, ocaml, typing, reason

I have the following code:

```
type cellInfo('a) = {
  index: int,
  column: column('a),
  id: string
};

type cellInfoFn('a) = cellInfo('a) => ReasonReact.reactElement;

type column('a) = {
  header: string,
  accessor: accessor('a),
  id: option(string),
  cell: cellInfoFn('a),
};
```

see how each type relies on each other.

I am getting the following error message:

```
[1]   12 │ type cellInfo('a) = {
[1]   13 │   index: int,
[1]   14 │   column: column('a),
[1]   15 │   id: string
[1]   16 │ };
[1]
[1]   This type constructor's parameter, `column`, can't be found. Is it a typo?
```

How do i handle mutually recursive type definitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutually recursive definitions must be separated by `and`. This goes for both `let` definitions and `type` definitions:

```
type cellInfo('a) = {
  index: int,
  column: column('a),
  id: string
}

and cellInfoFn('a) = cellInfo('a) => ReasonReact.reactElement

and column('a) = {
  header: string,
  accessor: accessor('a),
  id: option(string),
  cell: cellInfoFn('a),
};
```

Comment: That looks like it worked.  Thanks!  Is this possible/how does it look across multiple files?

Comment: No, they have to be defined in the same file. A common practice to deal with mutual recursion across files is to put them in the same file and then alias them back where they "belong".

Comment: does this work with modules too?  I guess they can be defined privately and placed into modules later.

Comment: It does work, as long as the modules are in the same file. You also have to use the `rec` keyword, like with `let`, and provide a signature for each module.